# Definition of the coset?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups

The definition of coset is as follow ( [from Wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coset)):

> In mathematics, if $G$ is a group, and $H$ is a subgroup of $G$, and $g$ is an
> element of $G$, then
>
> $gH$ = { $gh$ : $h$ is an element of $H$ } is the left coset of $H$ in $G$ with respect to $g$,
>
> $Hg$ = { $hg$ : $h$ an element of $H$ } is the right coset of $H$ in $G$ with respect to $g$.

I am confused that what is the rule of the $gh$ or $hg$ in definition. Is that multiplication or composition? If it is the law of composition, why notation $\circ$ is not used? If no, why is it only effective for groups under multiplication?

Could anyone help me out? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Wikipedia is using the (*very*) common convention of using multiplicative notation for a group, regardless of how the operation of a specific group may be defined or denoted. It would be more explicit to say, if $(G, *)$ is a group, the left cosets are defined by $g*H = \{g*h : h \in H\}$, etc.

So the operation used between an element $g$ and subgroup $H$ is whatever operation the group has, whether it's called multiplication, addition, composition, or some fourth thing. If you had a group with which you used additive notation, you'd write $g + H$ for cosets.

In theory you could do a similar thing, writing cosets as $g \circ H$ for groups whose operation is composition, but I can't say I've ever seen it. Often we just use multiplicative notation ("juxtaposition") even for groups whose operation is function composition. Really, you'll generally see juxtaposition used for almost every group that isn't written additively.

Comment: Great answer! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It is multiplication. Actually, a group $G$ is just a set equipped with a multiplication operation satisfying some axioms. So in that generality, you can't even talk about composition.

Comment: But the definition of the group is :  *A group is a set, $G$, together with an operation • (called the group law of $G$) that combines any two elements $a$ and $b$ to form another element*, which means that the addition operation could also satisfies $G$

Comment: Ah I see. The point is that whatever operation one is given for the group $G$, some authors will call it "multiplication". So $\mathbb{Z}$ is a group under the operation of addition of integers. But you might see this called a "multiplication" and written multiplicatively in some contexts. In particular, people will abbeviate $g \bullet h$ by $gh$.

Comment: Oh, I see. What a strange usage. Thank you very much!

Comment: No problem. Mathematics is full of notational quirks like this!

Answer (score 0):

Let's rewrite that a bit:

> If $(G, \star)$ is a group, and $(H, \star)$ is a subgroup of $G$, and $g$ is an
> element of $G$, then:
>
> - $g \star H$ = { $g \star h$ : $h$ is an element of $H$ } is the left coset of $H$ in $G$ with respect to $g$,
> - $H \star g$ = { $h \star g$ : $h$ an element of $H$ } is the right coset of $H$ in $G$ with respect to $g$.

Why isn't $\circ$ used?

- It's easier to write the product without symbols in between. Particularly $\circ$, which looks quite awkward!
- If desired, we associate the operation of multiplication with composition quite trivially, $g \circ h \equiv g \star h$. That's the great thing about groups. They preserve structures.

Also note that the order of the multiplication depends on convention. Particularly for composition, sometimes one author may write $f \circ g \circ h = fgh$ but another may write it as $f \circ g \circ h = hgf$.